# No direct object in this sentence, "Nihil igitur mors est, quoniam natura animi habetur mortalis."

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, wheelocks-latin

I translated this as "Therefore death is nothing, since the nature of the death is held by the mind."

> Nihil igitur mors est, quoniam nātūra animī habētur mortālis.

[image: Original sentence from the book]

Wouldn't mortalis have to be the direct object since natura and animi are already ablative and genitive respectively? Why is mortalis not accusative or ablative, given that it only makes sense for it to be the direct object of the passive verb habetur in this context? How do you suggest that I translate this?

Comment: Since this text shows macrons, "nātūra" cannot be ablative.  Given that habētur is passive, there cannot be a direct object.  Habeō has other usages than as an equivalent of "hold" or "have."  Try using the meaning "consider."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A couple of things:

- The fact that there are already an ablative and a genitive in a sentence doesn't preclude their being other ablatives and genitives in that sentence.
- *Mortalis* is an adjective, not a form of the noun *mors*. It's nominative. Even if it were genitive, it would be very odd to construe it with *natura*, as you've done in your translation, because the 2 words are so far apart.
- *Natura* is nominative, not ablative. You know this because your text (Wheelock's Latin if I'm not mistaken) has provided the long marks over vowels.
- Although you correctly state that *animi* is genitive in your last paragraph, you translated it as an ablative.
- Passive verbs can't take direct objects.
- *Habere* can mean to 'to consider.' Therefore, in the passive, it means 'to be considered,' and can function as a copula (linking verb) connecting a subject and a complement.

Comment: So "Since the nature of the mortal mind is considered", considering what you told me that seems correct.

Comment: Hmm, I think the answer is still missing a roundup sentence to put it all together. Very comprehensive BTW!

Comment: @Hydrolox3552 "since the nature of the mind is considered mortal", I think

Comment: Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it. This is exactly why I wanted to go back and translate these sentences, I had forgotten most of what I learned about passive verbs.